# Problems with setting contrasts for ANOVA in R

Tags: r, statistics, anova

For testing a specific hypothesis, I am trying to contrast a factor in R.

```
set.seed(24)
data <- data.frame(var = sample(1:100, 70, replace = TRUE),
              version = rep(c("v3", "v4", "v1", "v3", "v4","v2","v2"),times=10)) 

c1 <- c(1/3, -1, 1/3, 1/3) 
c2 <- c(0, -1, 1, 0) 
c3 <- c(0, -1, 0, 1)
c4 <- c(1, -1, 0, 0) 

mat <- cbind(c1, c2, c3, c4)

contrasts(data$version, how.many = 4) <- mat

model <- aov(var ~ version, data = data)

summary.aov(model, split=list(version=list("comparison1"=1,"comparison2"= 2,
                                       "comparison3"=3,"comparison4"= 4)))
```

Why is there no result for comparison 4? How can I fix that? Thanks.

Comment: there is a `how.many` parameter

Answer (score 2):

We specify the `how.many` parameter and it should work.  According to `?contrasts`

> how.many -How many contrasts should be made. Defaults to one less than the number of levels of x. This need not be the same as the number of columns of value.

So, it is the default behavior we observe while doing the assignment without any `how.many` parameter

```
contrasts(data$var, how.many = 4) <- mat
contrasts(data$var)
#             c1 c2 c3 c4
#var1  0.3333333  0  0  1
#var2 -1.0000000 -1 -1 -1
#var3  0.3333333  1  0  0
#var4  0.3333333  0  1  0
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
data <- data.frame(var = sample(paste0("var", 1:4), 20, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. But I still miss the last condition in my results when I enter: summary.aov(model_1, split=list(cond=list("con1"=1, "con2" = 2, 
                                                    "con3"=3, "con4" = 4))) Do you know why?

Comment: @kairos Hmm, now, it looks like a totally different question.  From my understanding, one of the levels of the factor variable is used as a base level.  The way of  assigning the base level may be different in different softwares (e.g. SAS vs R),

Comment: @kairos You can also check [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26539/r-linear-regression-categorical-variable-hidden-value)